# What's the difference between ( and [?

Tags: java, regex

What's the difference between `[pattern]` and `(pattern)`? I couldn't find it on google as it doesn't allow to type those symbols. Thanks.

Comment: Just read up on regular expressions on wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything in `[]` matches just one character.  So you might write `[aeiou]` to match any lower case vowel, or `[a-m]` to match any letter in the first half of the alphabet.  Because it's just one character, you may need to use it in combination with `+` or `*` if you want multiple characters.  For example,

`f[aeiou]t` matches `fat` but not `feet`, whereas `f[aeiou]*t` matches `fat`, `foot`, `feet` and even `ft`.

On the other hand, something in `()` matches as many characters as it would without the parentheses.  You use `()` if you want to operate with some portion of the regular expression.  For example, `ba(na)*` matches `ba` and `banana` and even `banananana`, because the `*` (which means any number of occurrences of whatever is immediately before it) acts on the whole `na`.  Also, if you're going to do replacement based on regular expressions, where you replace some part of the match with a new string, the `()` can be used to delimit what will be replaced - so, for example, you might replace whichever part of your string matches the 4th parenthesised expression.

Answer (score 11):

`()` is for a *group* (typically used for captures, alternation etc) whereas `[]` is for a *set* of characters (or one form of a "character class" to be precise).

So a pattern of `(abc)` will match the entire string `"abc"` whereas `[abc]` will match *any single character* out of `a`, `b` or `c`.

Although there are platform-specific aspects to regular expressions, this difference is pretty standard - so any regular expression tutorial should cover it.